# Mailto link causes blank page

Tags: 7

I just attempted to add an e-mail address link to a drupal page putting

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com">Contact us</a>
```

on the page. I then preview it, and no content shows up but the title. I remove the link and all the text is back again. What is causing this and how can I fix it? The strange thing is I have pages made earlier that already have mailto links on them.

Edit: I've tried this with both filtered and full HTML. I also have Invisimail installed, which does some e-mail filtering.

(I also couldn't get filtered html to turn a e-mail address into a hyperlink, but then discovered it was because it was in a `<strong>` block.)

Comment: Sounds like a filter issue, which input filter are you using and do you have any contrib modules which apply filtering?

Comment: Have you tried disabling invisimail to see if this helps at all?

Comment: Bizarre. Discovered the fake address above works, while the real one I'm using breaks it. I disabled and re-enable Invisimail and it works in both cases now. Seems odd that would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, you could try using the [Bbcode](http://drupal.org/project/bbcode) module.  The advantage here is that you can turn Email address encoding on, so your address isn't spammed.  (If you want this feature without the Bbcode module, you could use the [SpamSpan](http://drupal.org/project/spamspan) module.)

Sorry, I can't tell you how to fix your issue... but this may possibly be a workaround if all else fails?